# Adding a new field to a view

Tags: java, sql

I have a java web application I'm working on in an Eclipse environment.

For one of the views I'm using, I need to add a field to its select statement.  So, I've gone to the CreateViews.sql file and modified the SELECT query like so...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DBO.W_TRANSACTION_VIEW
    (ID,
     TYPE,
     CONTEXT,
     MYNEWFIELD)
AS
SELECT 
   tx.id,
   tx.type,
   tx.context,
   tx.mynewfield
FROM
   DBO.W_TRANSACTION tx
WHERE tx.deleted=0
WITH READ ONLY;
```

I was thinking that once I saved the CreateViews.sql file and then re-built the ear file via Ant, the field would then show up in the view.  However, it's not there.

Is there something else I need to do to propagate the change to the view?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there some code to run your CreateView.sql otherwise how you except that this view is created. You should manually run it on db.

Comment: Agreed with @erhun. You are only updating an sql file. You do not seem to be actually updating the view in your database.